# Saving JSON data with many properties in a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, json

I have data in sets like this:

```
**SET 1:**
Time = 2017-11-01 13:18:10 
Param1 = 42.42
Param2 = 47.11
Param3 = 12.34
.... (up to 100 parameters)

**SET 2:**
Time = 2017-11-01 13:18:20
Param1 = 45.17
Param2 = 46.11
Param3 = 12.35
.... (up to 100 parameters)
```

I get a new set of data every 10 second. I need so save data in SQL Server (I am free to define the table).

Later I need to fetch the data from the database so that I can XY graph having time on X-axis and the params on Y-axis.

I was thinking of saving my data as JSON. Either just as a string in a table (where the string is JSON) or use the JSON support in SQL Server 2016.

What is the recommended way of doing this?
I am thinking a lot on performance.

---

I did some tests:

Simple String: This is just for reference. My data colum simply contains a string with a 5 digit number.

XML String With attributes: Data column is a string (nvarchar(MAX)) containing XML with 35 nodes like this:

```
<data>
    <Regtime value='2017 - 08 - 21 13:56:05'/>
    <MachineId value = 'Somefactory.SomeSite.DeviceId' />    
    <Values>
        <B_T_SP value = '181.23' unit = '1234' />
        <B_H_SP_Tdp value = '87.34' unit = '801' />
        <B_A_SP_v_air value = '42.42' unit = '500' />
        <S_T_SP value = '175' unit = '801' />
        <S_A_SP_v_air value = '57.23' unit = '500' 
        ...
```

XML String with nodes: Same as above but not using attributes:

```
<data>
    <Regtime>'2017-11-01T12:59:02.2792518+01:00'</Regtime>
    <MachineId>'Somefactory.SomeSite.DeviceId'</MachineId>   
    <Values>
        <B_T_SP> 
            <value>666,50</value>
            <unit>801</unit>
        </B_T_SP>
        <B_H_SP_Tdp> 
            <value>414,21</value>
            <unit>801</unit>
        </B_H_SP_Tdp>
        <B_A_SP_v_air> 
            <value>41,83</value>
            <unit>801</unit>
        </B_A_SP_v_air>
        <S_T_SP> 
            <value>20,70</value>
            <unit>801</unit>
        </S_T_SP>                       
        ...
```

JSON string: Data column is a string (nvarchar(MAX)) containing JSON with 35 nodes like this:

```
{
              "data": {

                "Regtime": "2017-11-02T12:57:00.3745960+01:00",
                "MachineId": "Somefactory.SomeSite.DeviceId",
                "Values": {
                    "B_T_SP": {
                    "value": "703,81",
                    "unit": "801"

                  },
                  "B_H_SP_Tdp": {
                                "value": "485,90",
                    "unit": "801"

                  },
                  "B_A_SP_v_air": {
                                "value": "3,65",
                    "unit": "801"

                  },
                  "S_T_SP": {
                                "value": "130,44",
                    "unit": "801"

                  },    
                ...
```

Distributed: Like CodeCaster suggested, using two tables. 35 SetParameters per Set

When inserting data I do like this:

```
startTime = DateTime.Now;
            using (ConnectionScope cs = new ConnectionScope())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++)
                {
                    sql = GetSqlAddData(DataType.XmlAttributeString);
                    using (IDbCommand c = cs.CreateCommand(sql))
                    {
                        c.ExecuteScalar();
                    }
                }
            }
            logText.AppendText(string.Format("{0}x XML attribute string  Insert took \t{1}\r\n", counts, DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime)));
```

Except for Distribted, here I do like this:

```
using (ConnectionScope cs = new ConnectionScope())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++)
                {
                    sql = GetSqlAddData(DataType.Distributed);
                    using (IDbCommand c = cs.CreateCommand(sql))
                    {
                        id = (int)c.ExecuteScalar();
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < 35; j++)
                    {
                        using (IDbCommand c = cs.CreateCommand($"INSERT into test_datalog_distr_detail (setid, name, value) VALUES ({id}, '{"param"+j}', '{j*100 + i}')"))
                        {
                            c.ExecuteScalar();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            logText.AppendText(string.Format("{0}x Distributed Insert \t{1}\r\n", counts, DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime)));
```

When I read data I do like this:
Simple String:

```
var data = new List<Tuple<DateTime, string>>();
            DateTime time;
            string point;
string sql = GetSqlGetData(DataType.SimpleString);
            var startTime = DateTime.Now;
            using (ConnectionScope cs = new ConnectionScope())
            {
                using (IDbCommand cmd = cs.CreateCommand(sql))
                {
                    using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            time = DateTime.Parse(reader[5].ToString());
                            point = reader[12].ToString();
                            data.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, string>(time, point));

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            logText.AppendText(string.Format("{0}x Simple Select {1}\r\n", counts, DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime)));
```

XML both with and without nodes:

```
sql = GetSqlGetData(DataType.XmlAttributeString);
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            using (ConnectionScope cs = new ConnectionScope())
            {
                using (IDbCommand cmd = cs.CreateCommand(sql))
                {
                    using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            time = DateTime.Parse(reader[5].ToString());
                            doc = new XmlDocument();
                            doc.LoadXml(reader[12].ToString());
                            point = doc.SelectSingleNode("/data/Values/B_T_SP").Attributes["value"].Value;
                            data.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, string>(time, point));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            logText.AppendText(string.Format("{0}x Select using XmlDoc and Attribute String {1}\r\n", counts, DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime)));
```

JSON:

```
JObject jobj;
            using (ConnectionScope cs = new ConnectionScope())
            {
                using (IDbCommand cmd = cs.CreateCommand(sql))
                {
                    using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            time = DateTime.Parse(reader[5].ToString());
                            jobj = JObject.Parse(reader[12].ToString());
                            point = jobj["data"]["Values"]["B_T_SP"].ToString();
                            data.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, string>(time, point));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            logText.AppendText(string.Format("{0}x Select using JSON String {1}\r\n", counts, DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime)));
```

Distributed tables (CodeCaster recommendation)

```
sql = GetSqlGetData(DataType.Distributed);
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            using (ConnectionScope cs = new ConnectionScope())
            {
                using (IDbCommand cmd = cs.CreateCommand(sql))
                {
                    using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            time = DateTime.Parse(reader[5].ToString());
                            point = reader[15].ToString();
                            data.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, string>(time, point));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            logText.AppendText(string.Format("{0}x Select on distributed tables {1}\r\n", counts, DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime)));
```

I did a test run where I was inserting 100000 rows to the database and measured the time used:

```
Simple string value:      18 seconds
XML string (attributes):  36 seconds
XML string (nodes only):  38 seconds
JSON string:              37 seconds
Distributed (CodeCaster): 8 MINUTES!
```

Reading 100000 rows and fetch one value in each:

```
Simple string value:      0.4 seconds
XML string (attributes):  5.8 seconds
XML string (nodes only):  7.4 seconds
JSON string:              9.4 seconds
Distributed (CodeCaster): 0.5 seconds
```

So far my conclusion is:
I am surprised that XML seems faster than JSON. I expected distributed select to be faster than XML especially because the selection of one parameter is done in SQL and not afterwards as with JSON ans XML. But insert into distributed tables worries me. What I need more to test is to have the XML and XML in DB and not string so that I can select which parameter to use in SQL and not afterwards in XmlDocument

Comment: SQL Server 2016 does have JSON support but that doesn't include a JSON data type. It will still be stored as varchar (or nvarchar).

Comment: One other comment: My performance worries is both on when inserting and selecting data.

Comment: When you write "up to 100 parameters" you mean every set have the same amount of parameters (about 100) or that sets may have different amount of parameters (between 0 and 100)?

Comment: Different amount of parameters.

Comment: Then CodeCaster's answer is a good one. Usually, EAV is considered an anti-pattern, but sometimes it is the thing to do.

Comment: No comments? CodeCasters example is best for reading but writing performance is too bad. Is it possible to improve that?

Comment: That's because you insert each row individually. Use a table valued parameter to insert the attributes of each set. It should reduce insert time dramatically.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Actually [bulk insert](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+%5Bc%23%5D+bulk+insert) might have even better performance that using a [table valued parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+%5Bc%23%5D+insert+table+valued+parameter+).

Comment: I didn't know TVP before, but as far as I can read TVP might be faster thaan bulk insert in my case where I insert relative low amount of rows (10-100) relatively often. Am I right?

Comment: [Well, there is only one way to find out....](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I am doing some tests. I have been busy at some other stuff and had some days off. But I am planing some tests to figure out what is the best solution for me. I appreciate all the comments. Give me some more days to check this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to inform what I ended up doing:

`JSON` simply used up too much database space so I used a three level database structure, where I saved name of parameter in one table and parameter value in another table to reduce the footprint.

I then used Table Valued Parameters (TVP) to insert data in an effective way.

Answer (score 3):

Let's not store JSON in a database column, lest you want to create the inner platform effect or a database-in-a-database.

Especially not if you want to meaningfully query the data stored therein. Sure, there are database systems that support this, but if you have the ability to inspect and transform the JSON on beforehand, you should definitely go for that option.

Simply normalize the params into a junction table called SetParameters, with a foreign key to the Sets table.

So you'll end up with two tables:

`Sets`

- Id
- Time

`SetParameters`

- Id
- SetId
- Name
- Value

Comment: That was also my original idea. But because in my system I have 10-100 entities each sending one set (with 100 parameters) every 10 second. Isn't that being a lot of rows? I need to save data for at least a year. In order or keep row count down I wanted to save one data set in a single row

Comment: No, you don't want to keep the row count down. Databases are made for storing many rows.

Comment: @CodeCaster is right you do not want to be doing this, Databases are made to store large amounts of data so use that

Comment: Also, if you're afraid your primary table will grow too large, look into aggregating data into other tables, say montly and yearly ones and removing the source data.

Comment: Reading performance is very good, but writing is bad compared to XML/JSON. Unless it is possible to improve that somehow. The problem is that if I have 35 parameters I need to insert one row to Sets table and 35 rows to SetParameters every 10 second. With XML/JSON I only need one insert

Comment: @Claus look into bulk insert to insert all records at once, without 35 database roundtrips.